# How to insert an image before :topc: of asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Using `:top:` can auto-create table of content following title like this:

```
Title
 content table
```

But I want to insert an image before `:toc:` and after title like this:

```
Title
[logo]
  content table
```

How?

## Answer: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/toc/position/

```
= The Intrepid Chronicles
Kismet Lee; B. Steppenwolf; Pax Draeke
:toc: macro 

== Certain Peril

toc::[] 

Daylight trickles across the cobblestones...

== Dawn on the Plateau

Hanging from...
```

Comment: In the title and first line of this question, do you mean `:toc:` (rather than `:topc` and `:top:`)? If so, check out https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/toc/position/ especially `:toc: macro`

Comment: @nm wow, you are right!